# Datalogging square wave signal using GPIO.BOTH

Tags: pi-3, python, rpi.gpio

I'm currently making a datalogger using a Raspberry Pi which will record the real time and date of each falling and rising edge (GPIO BOTH) of a square wave signal (going through one input port). The date and time of each event needs to be recorded to a csv file on a connected USB. The signal will be continuous and so the GPIO BOTH needs to be in an infinite loop. I also need to code a safe shutdown mechanism in case the power to the Raspberry Pi cuts out. Does anyone know how I would go about coding this? I've attached the code I have written so far. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
import RPI.GPIO as GPIO
from datetime import datetime
import csv
from csv import writer

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)         # set up BCM GPIO numbering
GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.IN)        # set GPIO25 as input

# Define a threaded callback function to run in another thread when events are detected
def my_callback(channel):
     if GPIO.input(25):   # if port 25 == 1
          print "Rising edge detected"
     else:
         print "Falling edge detected"

while True:
    GPIO.add_event_detect(25, GPIO.BOTH, callback=my_callback)    # detect rising and falling edges on channel





with open('c:.....datalogger.csv', 'w', newline='') as Datalogger:
    data_writer = writer(Datalogger)

data_writer.writerow(['Edge type', 'Datetime'])

while True:
    data = GPIO.add_event_detect(25, GPIO.BOTH)
    data_writer.writerow(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be mixing up two different concepts to capture the change of state of the pin. That being the polling of the pin - something that would be done in an infinite loop - and setting up a callback function to act on a change of state. Using `GPIO.add_event_detect()` is setting up a callback function and it is something you do just once and not in a loop (and neither in two loops as the code indicates).

See [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Inputs/) for an example:

```
def my_callback(channel):
    print('This is a edge event callback function!')
    print('Edge detected on channel %s'%channel)
    print('This is run in a different thread to your main program')

GPIO.add_event_detect(channel, GPIO.RISING, callback=my_callback)  # add rising edge detection on a channel
...the rest of your program...
```

So the idea is to put the code you want to be run on a state change in that callback function. In your case that would be writing the event to the datalogger. Right now your callback is just printing to stdout. Meanwhile the rest of your program would be running from your main loop (or doing nothing).

```
def my_callback(channel):
     data_writer([GPIO.input(25), datetime.now()])


if __name__ == '__main__':

    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)      
    GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.IN)        

    with open('c:.....datalogger.csv', 'w', newline='') as Datalogger:
        data_writer = writer(Datalogger)

        # inform RPi.GPIO that we want it to call my_callback() on both edges of this pin
        # do this just once
        GPIO.add_event_detect(25, GPIO.BOTH, callback=my_callback)

        while True:
            # your main loop is here
            time.sleep(2)
```

By the way, note that this `data_writer.writerow(['Edge type', 'Datetime'])` will output just the literal strings "Edge type" and "Datetime", which is very likely not what you want.

> I also need to code a safe shutdown mechanism in case the power to the Raspberry Pi cuts out.

There is little to be done about that without additional hardware, i.e. if the power cuts out the Pi is dead and that is that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, much appreciated. I am new to python so I just need to clarify a few things you have shown. Does "data_writer([GPIO.input(25), datetime.now()])" mean that the CSV rows will be populated with one column showing whatever the value of the input at port 25 is and one column showing the real time and date? Also what does "if __name__ == '__main__': mean"? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Dan, "data_writer", yes that is what it should be doing. [`__name__ == '__main__'`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/419163/3984613) is a special thing to test whether your script is run on its own.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. Do I need to edit the "if name == 'main': mean" or leave it as it is? Is there any way to record the time of each measurement to a resolution of 1ms (using the datetime.now() I assume)? So I would have two columns in the CSV file saying either rising edge or falling edge, and also the date and time down to the millisecond....

Comment: You can skip the `__name__` stuff for now. `datetime.now()` prints microseconds resolution. Mind that resolution does not equal accuracy. Milliseconds should do fine (there should be a post about that somewhere but I just cannot find it). If you don't mind switching from `RPi.GPIO` to `pigpio` this could be interesting: http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html See also https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1015264

Comment: Hi @Ghanima, will the "__name__..." bit stop the code from running if there isn't a signal at input port 1? Also, can I delete the time.sleep(2) and just have while True: so it is constantly detecting the signal? Thanks for the pigpio link but I think I can get the RPI.GPIO to work, hopefuly..

Comment: @Dan note that it will be constantly detecting the signal, despite the sleep, that is the idea if the callback function. You can decrease the sleep (but you should not ommitt it) or replace it with the rest of your programm.

Comment: Hi @Ghanima, I've begun testing the code but I now get a 'RuntimeError: Failed to add edge detection'. Do you have any idea why this might happen? I've seen that it could possibly be because I need to run it as root?